# Buildtool similar to bitbake for Windows

Tags: windows, build, configuration-management, bitbake

Is there any build tool running in Windows environment that manages versions of modules in a set of recipes? Recipes should define from which source to build, how to build, and dependencies between the modules. I'd like the above meta-data about the module to be separated from the code its building, not like Ant/Ivy or Gradle (as a version/dependency file in the source repo).

I like the way package dependency handling in Linux work.

Actually, I want bitbake for Windows. Is there something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pretty the same bitbake using [Yocto](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Main_Page) by Intel on Windows and with Eclipse plugin.